# How to keep sub-process running after main process has exited?

Tags: python, linux, windows, multiprocess

I have a requirement to use python to start a totally independent process. That means even the main process exited, the sub-process can still run.

Just like the shell in Linux:

```
#./a.out &
```

then even if the ssh connection is lost, then `a.out` can still keep running.

I need a similar but unified way across Linux and Windows

I have tried the multiprocessing module

```
import multiprocessing
import time
def fun():
    while True:
        print("Hello")
        time.sleep(3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(name="Fun", target=fun)
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()
    time.sleep(6)
```

If I set the `p.daemon = True`, then the `print("Hello")` will stop in 6s, just after the main process exited.

But if I set the `p.daemon = False`, the main process won't exit on time, and if I <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to force quit the main process, the `print("Hello")` will also be stopped.

So, is there any way the keep print this "`Hello`" even the main process has exited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `multiprocessing` module is generally used to split a huge task into multiple sub tasks and run them in parallel to improve performance.

In this case, you would want to use the `subprocess` module.

You can put your `fun` function in a seperate file(`sub.py`):

```
import time

while True:
    print("Hello")
    time.sleep(3)
```

Then you can call it from the main file(`main.py`):

```
from subprocess import Popen
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Popen(["python", "./sub.py"])
    time.sleep(6)
    print('Parent Exiting')
```

Comment: "sub.py" should be referenced relative to the current script directory: `sub_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'sub.py')`. The working directory (i.e. ".") could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

The subprocess module can do it. If you have a `.py` file like this:

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen([r'C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe'])
```

The file will end its run pretty quickly and exit, but `vlc.exe` will stay open.

In your case, because you want to use another function, you could in principle separate that into another `.py` file